# Getting host is not configured error when using next/image with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, next.js

I'm aware that when using Next.js image components without TypeScript, the URL needs to be configured in `next.config.js`, but I'm not sure why this doesn't work with TypeScript.

> ...., is not configured under images in your `next.config.js` See more
> info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/next-image-unconfigured-host

What's the workaround? or is my only option to use a regular `img` tag?

image component:

```
<Image
    src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1621794279356-0150106a4b45?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&ixlib=rb-1.2.1"
    alt="blog title"
    width="100"
    height="100"
/>
```

`next.config.ts`

```
export const images = {
  domains: [
    "images.unsplash.com"
  ],
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should better use `next.config.js` for configuring next instead of `next.config.ts` in typescript project. This should be the only file to be in `.js`.

If you insist to use `next.config.ts`, you can refer to this [issue](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/5318).

But again, some may slow down the boot up time, and some still require you to have `next.config.js` alongside with `next.config.ts`

Answer (score 10):

Next.js will ultimately look for a `next.config.js` file to get the configurations from (which you most likely don't have if you're using `next.config.ts`).

Either you compile your `.ts` config to a `.js` config, or simply create a `next.config.js` file instead.

```js
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
    images: {
        domains: ['images.unsplash.com']
    }
}
```

---

From Next.js 12, you can now keep using ES modules by renaming the config file to `next.config.mjs`. While this isn't exactly the same as using TypeScript, at least you can keep the syntax consistent.

```js
// next.config.mjs
export default {
    images: {
        domains: ['images.unsplash.com']
    }
}
```